# Setting Request Headers in Ruby

Tags: ruby, rest

I have the rest client gem and I am defining a request like this:

```
url = 'http://someurl'
request =  {"data" => data}.to_json
response = RestClient.post(url,request,:content_type => :json, :accept => :json)
```

However I need to set the HTTP header to something. For example an API key. Which could be done in curl as:

```
curl -XHEAD -H x-auth-user: myusername -H x-auth-key: mykey "url"
```

Whats the best way to do this in ruby? Using this gem? Or can I do it manually to have more control.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

[The third parameter is the headers hash](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client/blob/master/lib/restclient.rb#L71).

You can do what you want by:

```
response = RestClient.post( 
  url, 
  request,
  :content_type => :json, :accept => :json, :'x-auth-key' => "mykey")
```

Comment: `-` is no a valid caracter in for a `Symbol`.

Comment: @MaurícioLinhares Actually, you can use :'x-auth-key' as a symbol, but not :x-auth-key . See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134702/ruby-1-9-hash-with-a-dash-in-a-key

Answer (score 22):

You can also do this

```
RestClient::Request.execute(
   :method => :get or :post,
   :url => your_url,
   :headers => {key => value}
)
```

Comment: extremely helpful, thanks, didnt see that :headers => {} in the docs

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with Rest-Client (1.7.2) I need to put both params and HTTP headers.

I solved with this syntax:

```
params = {id: id, device: device, status: status}
headers = {myheader: "giorgio"}

RestClient.put url, params, headers
```

I hate RestClient :-)

Answer (score 0):

If `PUT` isn't allowed we can pass it in the header of `POST`. Headers in bold. This worked for me:

`act_resp = RestClient.post url, req_param, **:content_type => :json, :method => :put*`*